# Travis-ci gets stuck in pods installation

Tags: ios, cocoapods, travis-ci

I'm trying to configure **Travis-CI** on my GitHub repo using the following configurations

#### .travis.yml

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode11.2

xcode_workspace: NinchatSDK.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: NinchatSDK
xcode_destination: platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.2,name=iPhone 8

before_install:
  - git submodule update --init --recursive

  - brew install go
  - go get -u golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
  - export PATH=$PATH:~/go/bin
  - gomobile init
  - ./update-go-framework.sh

  - gem install cocoapods
  - gem update concurrent-ruby
  - pod setup

script:
  - xcodebuild -workspace NinchatSDK.xcworkspace -scheme NinchatSDK -configuration "Release"
```

#### Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/somia/ninchat-podspecs.git'

def all_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'NinchatLowLevelClient', '~> 0'
    pod 'GoogleWebRTC', '~> 1.1'
    #pod 'NinchatLowLevelClient', :path => '.'
end

target 'NinchatSDK' do
  all_pods
end

target 'NinchatSDKTests' do
  all_pods
end
```

## Problem

The build server gets stuck in cocoapods installation and returns the timeout error after some time:

```
Cloning spec repo 'cocoapods' from 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates ....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use source `'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` instead of `'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`.

With recent versions of CocoaPods it should be way faster and also more reliable.